# Azure Logic Apps - JSON Parsing - Decimal type parsed as Integer

Tags: azure-logic-apps, jsonschema

I'm using Azure Logic apps and one of the steps is to parse an API JSON response. I'm uploading a payload to generate the schema.

One of my properties is a decimal type for Tax, specific in the JSON as “Number” type
The value in my source JSON comes through as this…

```
"TaxAmount": 999.00
```

However when its parsed it is set as "Integer"

When I change the value to...

```
"TaxAmount": 999.01
```

It will correctly come through as a "Number" type

Is there a way I can define the value of 999.00 and it be parsed as a “Number” rather than an “Integer”?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, no.

> Some programming languages and parsers use different internal
> representations for floating point numbers than they do for integers.
>
> For consistency, integer JSON numbers SHOULD NOT be encoded with a
> fractional part.

https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#integers

Note that this is SHOULD NOT, so it MAY be allowable.
But, consider, implementations may behave differently.
"SHOULD NOT" means, "you really should not do this unless you have a really good reason, and you better document it if you do".

If you need this, consider encoding the numbers in strings and using regular expression to do the validation.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to directly(i.e., manually) change the type of the variable while parsing. Something like

[image]

to

[image]